# Mirror image of a point about a line

Tags: geometry

How can I calculate the mirrored position for a point in 2D space? I know the xy-coordinates of the two points which define the vector. I also know the coordinates for the yellow point which I want to find the mirror image of.

How do I find the mirror image of the yellow point, when reflected about the vector created by the two red points?

I know how to find the vector that is easy bu subtracting the two points and the normalizing that value.

```
vec = normalize ([0,5] - [5,0])
vec = [-0.707107,0.707107]
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the *Mathematica* code you have tried, and point out where exactly you have difficulties.

Comment: @Jens I was looking here for reference but im not a math wizard so i was hoping someone could help me out. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Reflection.html. I know how to find the vector. that is easy. but what do i do after that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking about the maths or the software *Mathematica*?

Comment: @Jens I'm asking about the math. I update the question.

Comment: Have you looked at `ReflectionTransform`?

Comment: @JasonB its similar to the url i posted in the comments above. I still do not understand how to move forward on finding any answer.

Answer (score 3):

The given points:

```
p1 = {0, 5}; p2 = {5, 0}; p3 = {6, 5};
```

A vector perpendicular to `p2 - p1`:

```
normal = RotationTransform[90 °][p2 - p1];
```

The reflection transform of a mirror placed at `p1` having `normal` as its normal -- i.e., the mirror that is perpendicular to the line through `p1` and `p2`:

```
rF = ReflectionTransform[normal, p1];
```

The image of `p3` as given by `rF`:

```
p4 = rF[normal, p1][p3]
```

> `{0, -1}`

Plot verifying the result:

```
Graphics[{Arrow[{p1, p2}], Arrow[{p3, p4}]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot]